# Replacing in the selected blocks of text end of line characters to spaces

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I have text file:

```
    gvim file.txt


In UNIX you can type this at any command prompt.  If you are running Microsoft
Windows, open an MS-DOS prompt window and enter the command.
   In either case, Vim starts editing a file called file.txt.  Because this
is a new file, you get a blank window. This is what your screen will look
like:



    +---------------------------------------+
    |#                                      |
    |~                                      |
    |~                                      |
    |~                                      |
    |~                                      |
    |"file.txt" [New file]                  |
    +---------------------------------------+
          ('#" is the cursor position.)

The tilde (~) lines indicate lines not in the file.  In other words, when Vim
runs out of file to display, it displays tilde lines.  At the bottom of the
screen, a message line indicates the file is named file.txt and shows that you
are creating a new file.  The message information is temporary and other
information overwrites it.
```

Tree file:

```
^$
text. text\n   - join lines in this block, because ends block dot
more text.\n
^$
^$
text.\n
text: text\n    - join lines in this block, because ends block >
more text>\n
^$
text.\n   - but not this, because don't ends '., :, > or !'
text\n
^$
```

---

TASK:

1. I want to select a block of text with more than one line ending with `.`, `:`, `>` or `!` using only regex
2. Replace end of line characters to spaces
3. How do I do this with vim, bash, perl, or awk to solve this task.

I want understand the difference in the operation, to select the best tool for working with text.

---

Trying to create a regex in Vim:

1. `/^\s*\(.*\).`

   this select all block text
2. `/[!\.:>]$`

   this select ended `.`, `:`, `>` or `!`
3. `/^\s*\(.*\)[!\.:>]$`

   this select only line ended `.`, `:`, `>` or `!`
4. `/^\s*\(.*\)[!\.:>]`

   this select only line containing `.`, `:`, `>` or `!` therein

Answer (score 0):

to select a single line with multiple line endings:

`/^(.*)[!.:>]$/;`

If I was to attempt to process the block using perl then I would process it one line at a time and match each one.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, if you're main purpose is to fix the line ending differences between Unix and Windows, it's worth knowing that the simple Unix tool [`dos2unix`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_dos2uni.htm) will convert text files in either direction.

Comment: I have a lot of files edited in Vim. Limit the width of text to 80 characters in line. I want to maintain the formatting of the document at the same time add lines of text as part of the opinion that vim shortened to 80 characters.

Comment: @RA: I don't understand that remark (sentence doesn't parse), but you might find what you want with `:he 'formatoptions'` and `:he 'formatprg'` and their friends (also man par(1))

Answer (score 0):

In vim, do this:

```
:#s/^(.*)[!.:>]$/ /gc;
```